# How to check the app was installed by apk or not

Tags: android, google-play

I need to check the app was installed by apk or from google play.

I have an **apk that was downloaded from google play**, and also, the app was available on google play. I want to classify two cases.

I already read about this question below, but it is about which app store the application was installed by, And it was not I want.
[How does android package manager know what to install from the market place web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330788/how-does-android-package-manager-know-what-to-install-from-the-market-place-web)

Is there any method to check the app was installed by apk or not, programmatically by app itself? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, find Installer package name, like:

```java
String sourceId = getPackageManager()
    .getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName());
```

Then check the `sourceId` variable's value, like:

- If App was installed from Google play store, said value should be:

```
com.android.vending
```

- If installed from Google play store, then extracted `APK`, and installed again:

```
com.google.android.packageinstaller
```

- If download from Google play store *publish*, App release list:

```
null
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but my problem is, the app was downloaded from google play. That means, I can get same installer package names in both cases.

Comment: okay, let me check... if I got anything... I will let you know

Comment: Oh, you are right. I tested some cases, and add details to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

if(pm.getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName()).equals("com.android.vending"){
   //App is from google play
   //do something
}
```

app with unknown source will return empty string

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to check, if a apk was downloaded from a store or sideloaded:

```
private boolean isStoreVersion(Context context) {
    boolean isStoreVersion= false;

    try {
        String installer = context.getPackageManager()
                                    .getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());
        isStoreVersion= !TextUtils.isEmpty(installer);
    } catch (Throwable e) {      
           e.printStackTrace();    
    }

    return isStoreVersion;
```

}